# How to insert CSV data containing "string"string" into table

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

Given a CSV file with the following:

```
id,description,val
111,"abc",0
112,"abc"def",0
```

How do I insert this data into an SQL Server table using SSIS?

I've currently specified my column delimiter as <kbd>,</kbd> and the text qualifier <kbd>"</kbd>

Comment: using sql-server-2012..

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below step by step walk-though. The settings you have done are right for  flat file connection manager.

[Import CSV File into Database Table Using SSIS](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/12/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-database-table-using-ssis/)